# JavaScript Regex for first character alphabet only, second and onwards can be alphanumeric or special characters (hyphen, comma and whitespace)

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I need help in regex where first character alphabet only, second and onwards can be alphanumeric or special characters (hyphen, comma and whitespace).

I tried below its is not working.

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -,]+$
```

Comment: Put the `-` character last in the second character class, otherwise it would be interpreted as "all characters from space to comma".

Comment: Do I understand correctly, after the first character onwards, there can be anything?

Comment: after first character, all alphanumeric and few special characters hyphen, comma and whitespace are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, simply escape `-` in the second character set, like so:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 \-,]+$
```

Otherwise, as pointed out by @Sweeper in the comments, `-,` would match any character between  and `,`.

See [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ksmdlW/1).

Comment: Just a heads up to not confuse beginners. The `[]` brackets are not called group, a character group is within these `()` brackets. The ones you use are called *Character Classes* or *Character Sets*